# Eclipse The type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, class, protocol-buffers

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Adding grpc-protobuf-1.16.1.jar to the classpath didn't help.
Can someone help?

Comment: Try with **protobuf-java-2.4.1** or any other version